# Adding Breakpoint to Lambda Function

Tags: c#, sharepoint, lambda

I'm trying to debug a lamba in my c# code but it seems no matter where in the lambda i put the breakpoint it won't go into it. I've put it on the first bracket, the last bracket, the return, the variable I want to see the value of, everything I can think of and still nothing.

When trying to debug any line outside of the lambda it does it no problem, what am I doing wrong?

Lambda is below:

```
clientProgramList.Items.OfType<SPListItem>().Where(x =>
{
    DateTime doa = x.GetValue<DateTime>("client1");
    DateTime dod = x.GetValue<DateTime>("client2");
    bool date = DateCompare.IsValidClient(enteredDate, endDate, doa, dod); 
    return date;
});
```

Comment: In addition to the below answers, make sure that `clientProgramList.Items.OfType<SPListItem>()` actually has at least one item. If the collection is empty, the `Where` predicate won't be called.

Comment: Also if you have a list of non-trivial size consider performing the query on the DB end of things, rather than in memory using Linq to Objects.

Comment: @AdamMaras it does :) first thing I checked

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just calling the `Where` method doesn't *execute* the predicate at all.

Due to LINQ's deferred execution method, the predicate isn't executed until you try to iterate over the return value - which in this case it seems you're ignoring.

So if you do:

```
var items = clientProgramList.Items.OfType<SPListItem>().Where(x =>
{
    DateTime doa = x.GetValue<DateTime>("client1");
    DateTime dod = x.GetValue<DateTime>("client2");
    bool date = DateCompare.IsValidClient(enteredDate, endDate, doa, dod); 
    return date;
});

int count = items.Count();
```

then your break-point should be hit when you try to execute `Count()`.

Answer (score 7):

When you call that `LINQ` query, lambda is not being called, instead only query is being constructed. `Where` clause is lazily evaluated (only when you start to iterate over items). Try to add `ToList()` at the end of the query and see if breakpoint is hit.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot debug a lambda the same way you can debug other code.  A lambda is 'lazy' executed, meaning that is not evaluated until the value is used.  Until then, it is just a queued up query.

If the bug you are trying to track down is a ArgumentException, it most likely means that `clientProgramList.Items` is null, which is something you can easily check with your debugger.